# Kill a process based on parts of its name over ssh (different results when running interactive ssh session)

Tags: ssh, kill

I am trying to do:

Fing the pid of process based on something I grep for, lets say "Name":

```
pid=(ps aux | grep '[Ń]ame' | awk '{print $2}' | head -1)
```

Then kill it

```
kill $pid
```

This works fine if I log into the machine with ssh, but I want to do it from a script. And it doesn't work then:

```
ssh hostname "pid=\$(ps aux | grep '[N]ame' | awk '{print $2}' | head -1); echo \$pid"
root 11203 1.5 0.8 6961292 135420 pts/0 Sl 16:52 0:04 java -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dproperties....
```

I would like to know a way of doing this and why the results are different when doing the command as in the latter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pgrep to simplify the search and pipe the result with xargs to remove the use of vars, like:

```
ssh hostname "pgrep emacs | head -1 | xargs echo"
```

Your main problem is that bash try to evaluate $2 in the ssh command. It results to a blank, so interprets that you want to pipe `awk '{print }' instead. You can also try to execute with another escape character:

```
ssh hostname "pid=\$(ps aux | grep '[N]ame' | awk '{print \$2}' | head -1); echo \$pid"
```

That version works.

Answer (score 1):

[`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) has a `-r` option to match process name on a regular expression.

> -r, --regexp Interpret process name pattern as an extended regular expression.